# Show that $f(x) = \log(x + \sqrt {x^2+1})$ is an odd function

Tags: functions

I need to show that $f(x) = \log(x + \sqrt{x^2+1})$ is an odd function and from what I can understand from this question (found while searching): [What is an odd function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498670/what-is-an-odd-function), I have to show that$f(-x)=-f(x)$. I have struggled to figure it out for hours but I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$\log(\frac 1 x)=-\log (x)$$

Comment: Use \log for $\log$. Fixed.

Comment: @NaN Sure, I'll take care of it next time :)

Comment: BTW $f(x)=\sinh^{-1} x$ which gives you another way of proving it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$$f(x)+f(-x)=\log\left[\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\cdot\left(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\right]=\log(x^2+1-x^2)=0.$$

Comment: Exploiting properties of $\log $ , simply brilliant.

Comment: The beauty of this question lies in this answer. :)

Answer (score 14):

$$f(-x) = \ln\left(-x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right) = \ln\left( \left(-x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right) \frac{x +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}  \right) \\ = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\right) = -f(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

use $$(a-b)*(a+b) = a^2 - b^2$$ and $$\log\frac{1}{a} = - \log(a) $$ properties.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $f(-x)$ is odd if and only if $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Now, we have $$f(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$ setting $x=-x$, we get $$f(-x)=\log((-x)+\sqrt{(-x)^2+1})$$ $$f(-x)=\log(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$ $$=\log(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$$$$=-\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}\right)$$ $$=-\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)}\right)$$  $$=-\log\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{(\sqrt{x^2+1})^2-(x)^2}\right)$$  $$=-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$$$=-f(x)$$  Hence the given function $f(x)$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Can we Use The fact that If $f'(x)$ is an even function, Then function $f(x)$ is odd.

or If If $f'(x)$ is an odd function, Then function $f(x)$ is even.

So Here $$\displaystyle f(x) = \ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\right]$$

So $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}\cdot \left(1+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

So Here $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\;,$$ So $$f'(-x) = f'(x)$$ So Here $f(x)$ is an even function.

So Function $f(x) = \ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$ is an Odd function.

Answer (score 0):

f(x)= log(x+√x^2+1)
f(-x)=log(-x+√x^2+1)
f(x)+f(-x)=log[(x+√x^2+x).(x+√x^2+1)
f(x)=(x^2+1-x^2)
f(1)= 0
Hance,f(x)Isan odd function